# Ruby on Rails 3: Sort an index view by virtual attribute or create a table column instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an Invoicing application where an Invoice has many Items and Payments.

In my index view I am showing a list of all Invoices including two virtual attributes:

```
def total
  items.sum { |item| item.total }
end

def balance
  self.payments.sum(:amount) - self.total
end
```

I noticed that an aweful lot of SQL is needed to display the index view. Would it be advisable to create two more table columns instead? So far, I chose not to because I don't like having too much redundant data.

This is my **controller**:

```
def index
  result = current_user.invoices.includes(:items, :payments)
  @invoices = paginate(result)
end
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<table id="index">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @invoices %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @invoices %>
```

**_invoice.html.erb**:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <%= link_to invoice.number, invoice_path(invoice) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= l invoice.date %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= number_to_currency(invoice.total) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= number_to_currency(invoice.balance) %>
</td>       
<td>
    <%= destroy_link(invoice) %>
</td>
</tr>
```

For each invoice on the index view these four SQL queries are being generated:

```
(0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("payments"."amount") AS sum_id FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."invoice_id" = 19
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."invoice_id" = 19
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT SUM("payments"."amount") AS sum_id FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."invoice_id" = 19
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."invoice_id" = 19
```

(That makes 40 SQL queries per index page.)

I must admit that I am relatively new to Rails. So I wonder if there's a Best Practice to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest improvement you could use here is eager loading.

When you load your `Invoice` objects, if you eager load the associated items and payments, you'll do 3 queries instead of, well, lots.

So, if you have a controller action that does something like this:

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all
end
```

you could change it to:

```
@invoices = Invoice.includes(:payments, :items).all
```

This change should speed things up quite a bit, and doesn't require that you change your `total` or `balance` methods - they still do the same thing, but fetch all the objects they need at once, instead of a few at a time.

Now, this is still (potentially, at least) loading rather a lot of objects into memory. If you're going to be displaying all sorts of data in that view related to the individual Items and Payments, there's probably nothing to be done. But if all the view needs are the total and balance values, you can make your database do this for you and skip instantiating the objects, like this:

```
@invoices = Invoice.select("invoices.*, sum(items.total) as item_total, (sum(payments.amount) - sum(items.total)) as remaining_balance").joins(:items, :payments).group('invoices.id')
```

When you use a custom select clause like this, the extra column get grafted onto the returned objects as attributes with the name of the column, so you can do:

```
@invoices.first.remaining_balance
```

I've used different names for these columns so that they don't overlap with your existing balance and total methods - you may or may not still need those, as these values only exist when the objects they're called on use the custom select described. If they were loaded without it, trying to call `.remaining_balance` would produce a NoMethodError.

Caveats: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.3, if you're not, the above may need to be modified slightly. Also, the adapter has an odd tendency to return these values as strings, so you may need to call `.to_f` or something similar on them.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I like your suggestion on Eager Loading and gave my best to implement what you suggested. However, for some reason the includes statement doesn't reduce the number of SQL queries at all in my case. It still takes around SQL 50 queries to display a mere 10 invoices in my index view. That's far too much, as you will agree. I posted my controller code above in my initial question. So maybe you can see what I am doing wrong there.

Comment: Hmm... could you include the relevant view as well? Also, what objects are all those queries loading? Are they Item and Payment objects? Also, what pagination method/tool are you using? I suppose it's possible that that is somehow overriding the eager loading.

Comment: Hello MrWalrus. Thanks for helping me with this. I would be lost without you on this. I tried to post some more code above, including an excerpt of the SQL queries. For some reason, there is still an SQL query for every single invoice item. For pagination I am using the will_paginate gem, version 3.0.

Comment: @Tintin81 I believe what's happening here is that `.sum` (in your total and balance methods) is deciding to run in the database, instead of using the loaded objects. Try redefining total as `items.map(&:total).sum` (and likewise use `payments.map(&:amount).sum` for calculating balance). That should force it to use the in memory objects. Whether this is actually more efficient overall is uncertain - if those SUM queries are the only ones you're seeing, you should seriously consider switching to the custom select and grouping method I described.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thanks a lot. The number of queries is greatly reduced now, only 4 or 5 left. Now I have to figure out why the *.map* method works better than my original one...